# Using JS function in another JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function

I have two JS files called `main.js` and `load.js`.

In `main.js` I have:

```
function removeItem() {
  alert('Item removed');
}
(function($) {  
    $(document).ready(function() {
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In `load.js` I have:

```
(function($) {  
    $(document).ready(function() {
      removeItem();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

My files are loaded in this order:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js?ver=3.6.0' id='script-jquery-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='url/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/main.js?ver=1.0' id='script-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='url/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/load.js?ver=1.0' id='script-load-js'></script>
```

It throws me an error:

```
removeItem() is not defined.
```

How can I use the function from `main.js` in `load.js`?

Comment: The problem is removeItem is not in global scope. It is defined within the ready function. Which means it is hidden, so you can not call it.

Comment: If I move the removeItem outside the document ready function it gives me the same error

Comment: Because you stuck it inside of the self executing function which takes it out of global scope.

Comment: I changed my script with the function removeItem out of function and now it works!